# Allowing +w permissions for a sub-directory to a team of users, without sudo access

Tags: permissions

I'm a non-admin user on a linux system. No sudo, so I can't manage any groups. A team of ~5 other users need shared access (+w) to a subfolder I created. I don't want to give 777 permissions on the folder, I only want the team to have full permission to everything in that folder.

What's the most efficient way to handle this?

Most discussions either suggest group's (sudo needed), or changing ownership. Neither seem right. I wasn't clear from searches if ACLs were the way to go, so if they are can you explain how that works for such a shared folder?

Comment: You forgot to say, why the users should have write access for that folder. Should they be able to just create files or be able to edit files?

Comment: These users should all have full 777 access to that folder and everything under it, and everything created by other users placed in that folder. I just want a shared workspace for the group.

Comment: Do you have a shared group you all belong to?  Permissions could be set to 2770 so owner and group have full permission and all created files will be owned by the same group.  Otherwise investigate ACLs.  `man setfacl`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the comments suggest, a shared group is the “proper” way to handle what you want.  But if that is not possible, you can use ACLs as you suggest.  You simply do `setfacl -m u:someuser:rwx thefolder` and repeat for each user you want to give access.